# How to get rid of "xmnls:xsi = ...." in output for XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

In my output, `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` is in my output. How can I get rid of it?

XML (input):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="items_schema.xsd"> 
    <Skyscraper>Willis Tower</Skyscraper> 
    <Small_fruit>blueberry</Small_fruit> 
    <Big_fruit>watermelon </Big_fruit> 
</items>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
            
            <xsl:template match="/items">   
                <xsl:variable name="fruit" select="*[contains(local-name(), 'fruit')]" />   
                <items>
                    <Building>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="* except $fruit"/>
                    </Building>
                    <Food>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$fruit"/>
                    </Food>
                </items>
            </xsl:template>
            
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML (Output, what actually happened):

```
<items> 
    <Building>
        <Skyscraper xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Willis Tower</Skyscraper>
    </Building> 
    <Food>
        <Small_fruit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">blueberry</Small_fruit> 
        <Big_fruit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">watermelon </Big_fruit> 
    </Food>
</items>
```

XML (Output, what I expected):

```
<items> 
    <Building>
        <Skyscraper>Willis Tower</Skyscraper>
    </Building> 
    <Food>
        <Small_fruit>blueberry</Small_fruit> 
        <Big_fruit>watermelon </Big_fruit> 
    </Food>
</items>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following XSLT.

By default, the `xsl:copy` instruction is copying namespaces from the input XML. To prevent it from happening we can use  `copy-namespaces="no"` attribute.

For the reference: [Copying Nodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-copy)

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"  omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/items">
        <xsl:variable name="fruit" select="*[contains(local-name(), 'fruit')]"/>
        <items>
            <Building>
                <xsl:copy-of select="* except $fruit" copy-namespaces="no"/>
            </Building>
            <Food>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$fruit" copy-namespaces="no"/>
            </Food>
        </items>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<items>
  <Building>
    <Skyscraper>Willis Tower</Skyscraper>
  </Building>
  <Food>
    <Small_fruit>blueberry</Small_fruit>
    <Big_fruit>watermelon </Big_fruit>
  </Food>
</items>
```

Comment: Perhaps enhance this with an explanation of the change.